# Instruct Android Gradle script to delete unaligned apks and clean artifact files

Tags: android, build, gradle

I started using Gradle build system a few days ago and got the script to work as I wanted, here it is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'


    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "flavor1"
        }
        flavor2 {
            packageName "flavor2"
        }
        flavor3 {
            packageName "flavor3"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file("test.keystore")
                storePassword "*****"
                keyAlias "****"
                keyPassword "*****"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

As you can see there is nothing fancy here just building 3 flavours of the app and signing them with the same key. I just run gradle assembleRelease and after 20 seconds I have my apks in build folder. But the problem is that there are other files generated that I don't want for example appname-release-unaligned.apk.

I know that this file is needed before apk can be signed but would like to add a task to delete these files in my gradle script?

Also if it's possible I would like to remove all other (shell I say artefact files) generated during build. Essentially I would like to run something like gradle clean but leave the build apk files. How do I do this?

BONUS:If anyone has pointers on how can I optimise this script and enable zip align and proguard (without custom rules just default obfuscation is ok) that would also help me since I am very new to gradle and none of the tutorials I followed explains these steps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE February 2018**.
This block will cause a build error using Android Gradle plugin 3.0 or above. See 'deepSymmetry's comment below.

The "fix" is to **delete the block altogether** and the plugin's default behavior will automatically clean up the intermediate temporary apks (ex: app-debug-unaligned.apk).

---

Pretty old topic but here is modern solution for deleting unnecessary 'unaligned' file. This is quite handy especially on CI servers to save some space.

That's a shame that plugin does not provide hook for 'zipAlign' task so we'll need to hook on 'assemble' task which goes after 'zipAlign'.

Works with last gradle plugin 1.2.0 (gradle-2.4) but should be valid for 1.+

```
// delete unaligned files
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant.assemble.doLast {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        println "aligned " + output.outputFile
        println "unaligned " + output.packageApplication.outputFile

        File unaligned = output.packageApplication.outputFile;
        File aligned = output.outputFile
        if (!unaligned.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aligned.getName())) {
            println "deleting " + unaligned.getName()
            unaligned.delete()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And another one if your prefer to check zipAlignEnable flag but in this case you'll be tied to "unaligned" constant in filename because release builds with zipAlignEnabled=true AND without signingConfig skip 'zipAlign' task and produce only one file: 'app-release-unsigned.apk'.

```
// delete unaligned files
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.assemble.doLast {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        println "aligned " + output.outputFile
        println "unaligned " + output.packageApplication.outputFile

        File file = output.packageApplication.outputFile;
        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled && file.getName().contains("unaligned")) {
            println "deleting " + file.getName()
            file.delete()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the first one in case anyone cares.

Comment: Thank you for the info. This one does seem like a good way to handle this. I will test it out.

Comment: Welcome.
Unlike currently accepted answer in my solution we don't need special task and don't have to copy files anywhere.

Comment: I just revisited this question and this indeed is a good solution for the problem I was having. Thus I am going to accept your answer and will be using it probably in the future.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: Still works good (also for gradle plugin 2.2.0). Using the first option.

Comment: With Gradle 3.0.0, it throws an error. `Could not get unknown property 'outputFile' for task ':app:SomeTask' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.` The migration guide talks about manifestOutputFile but not this one.

Comment: It turns out that deleting the unaligned apks is included in the android 3.0 gradle plugin by default, so if you are migrating a project to the new plugin (as I am now), just delete this block and you will still not have any unaligned apks - yay =)

Answer (score 9):

I noticed there is some activity on this question from time to time so here is the way I solved the problem if it helps someone. Just define new task to copy file and then set execution order.

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
   from 'build/apk'
   into 'apks'
   exclude '**/*-unaligned.apk'
}

task allTask(dependsOn: ['clean', 'assembleRelease', 'copyTask']){
    clean.mustRunAfter copyTask
    copyTask.mustRunAfter assembleRelease
}
```

then just call this allTask when you want to do a build.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least answer your bonus-question:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

If you have specific proguard-rules, just enter this line to your `defaultConfig` or to your product flavors:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

The first proguard rule is the generla one from your Android SDK, the second one is from your module-directory.

ZipAlign is enabled by default if you build you project with the build variant `release`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The proguard part quite helps. Could you just tell me shoud the rules txt be in the same place where eclipse puts one? Note that I kind of solved the above by creating bat script that calls build, than moves apks out than calls clean but I am still stuck on how to do this in gradle.

Comment: If no specific path is provided and just the plain filename is provided, the `proguard-rules.txt` is based in the module's directory (where the `build.gradle` is located.
But in general, you can put this file where you want. Besides, you have a different project structure if using Android Studio / Gradle, so more or less nothing stays in the same directory. Just create an empty new project and you will soon get it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit modified answer from @PSIXO, сonsidering Android Studio 1.5, running test cases and renaming apk file for better CI integration:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydemoci"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionName"
    }
}

task copyOutputApk(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/outputs/apk'
    into 'apk'
    exclude '**/*-unaligned.apk'
}

task buildTestDebug(dependsOn: ['clean', 'assembleDebug', 'check', 'copyOutputApk']) {
    check.mustRunAfter assembleDebug
    copyOutputApk.mustRunAfter check
    clean.mustRunAfter copyOutputApk
}
```

To start build run `gradlew buildTestDebug`