# How can I disable building unaligned apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In all time I build the project it's creates 2(!) apk files - debug and unaligned debug (default release building type I disable). But I DON'T NEED it 2 files on debug!! I need one - debug.apk.

I read official documentation about buildTypes and flavors, trying some methods, but it's also 2 files!

How can I change it?

Comment: [Its an intermediate step](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22058230/6126321). If you really hate it, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30826071/6126321).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instruct Android Grade script to delete unaligned apks and clean artefact files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857213/instruct-android-grade-script-to-delete-unaligned-apks-and-clean-artefact-files)

Comment: Ok, thanks Austyn. It's good solving to remove apk in other folder with exclude mask. But for debug build type I DON'T WANT TO GENERATE unaligned apk - it's not needed - I loss my time greater and building system do much works.

Comment: With the newest gradle build tools, like `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' }` , the unaligned file is automatically deleted.