# Delete unaligned apks using Gradle script in Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0/build tools 3.0.0, a piece of my Gradle build script (which is used to delete unaligned apks after assembling) failed during build.

FYI I was using the Gradle scripts from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857213/instruct-android-gradle-script-to-delete-unaligned-apks-and-clean-artifact-files).

Now it's always saying output.packageApplication.outputFile is an unknown property (`Could not get unknown property 'outputFile' for task...`).

I am wondering if there's an alternative way to get the unaligned file?

Any comment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of Gradle 2.2, there isn't an unaligned APK, so deleting it is unnecessary. (I just ran into this also - and noticed that they were missing.)

See the note here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121010

So your code to remove them is unnecessary.

Also, to address the failure - as of Gradle 3.0 there are some features that are not working (like the variant outputFile). See the reference here on how to avoid that error:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api